# How to crash a Sun OS (Solaris) machine through SSH?

Tags: crash, solaris

I want to crash a Sun OS (Solaris) machine through SSH.

Why do I want to do it? Because I want to test how some processes know how to recover after a crash.

I know that in Linux I can write the commands:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
nohup echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

And this crashes a Linux machine.

I want to know if Solaris (Sun OS) has a similar command.

Important: I don't want the machine to turned off after that. because next time that I connect through SSH I need it to be available.

Comment: The `halt -d` command might do it : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28983/fvzpo.html).

Comment: Hi I already tried this command and the machine is not available for the next time. After this command the machine "waits" to be turned-off manually

Comment: What version of SunOS? I assume you have tried the command?  You make no mention of what you tried.

Comment: Yes. I have tried the "halt -d" command. ant it's not available after this command
I'm using SunOS 11

Comment: I have tried "halt -d".

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?&q=solaris+emergency+reboot

Comment: What have you tried? What have you found? "I found something for linux" is not particularly helpful for Solaris. Why do you *need* to do this? What state does the system need to be in after? Rather than a command you will probably get a better response running the OS in a VM and simply switching the VM off, the result will be the same and you can do it in a more controlled fashion than relying on a network link to know if it has come back up

Comment: `man -a uadmin`